# Debugging works in command line but breakpoint is not hit in UI

Tags: unit-testing, go, visual-studio-code, delve

I have installed the following in my Windows 10 machine:

- VS Code - version 1.38.1
- Golang - version go1.13
- Delve - version 1.3.0

I have set GOROOT and GOPATH in environment variables. My GOPATH has the following three folders:

- src
- bin
- pkg

Under src, I have created a basic sam-app. It auto-creates main_test.go file. When I do 'debug test', breakpoint is not hitting in UI. Howerver, I am able to debug using dlv in command line.

- I have tried different configurations in launch.json. None of them worked. In my friend's machine, the UI Debugging works even without configurations
- In VS Code settings --> node debug --> auto attach --> I have set 'on'
- I have closed VS Code and re-opened. It did not work
- I have opened VS Code as Administrator, it did't work either
- I have uninstalled and reinstalled VS Code
- I have uninstalled and reinstalled Golang
- I have installed Go extension in VS Code

  ```
  package main

  import (
      "fmt"
      "net/http"
      "net/http/httptest"
      "testing"

      "github.com/aws/aws-lambda-go/events"
  )

  func TestHandler(t *testing.T) {
      t.Run("Unable to get IP", func(t *testing.T) {
          DefaultHTTPGetAddress = "http://127.0.0.1:12345"

          _, err := handler(events.APIGatewayProxyRequest{})
          if err == nil {
              t.Fatal("Error failed to trigger with an invalid request")
          }
      })

      t.Run("Non 200 Response", func(t *testing.T) {
          ts := httptest.NewServer(http.HandlerFunc(func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
              w.WriteHeader(500)
          }))
          defer ts.Close()

          DefaultHTTPGetAddress = ts.URL

          _, err := handler(events.APIGatewayProxyRequest{})
          if err != nil && err.Error() != ErrNon200Response.Error() {
              t.Fatalf("Error failed to trigger with an invalid HTTP response: %v", err)
          }
      })

      t.Run("Unable decode IP", func(t *testing.T) {
          ts := httptest.NewServer(http.HandlerFunc(func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
              w.WriteHeader(500)
          }))
          defer ts.Close()

          DefaultHTTPGetAddress = ts.URL

          _, err := handler(events.APIGatewayProxyRequest{})
          if err == nil {
              t.Fatal("Error failed to trigger with an invalid HTTP response")
          }
      })

      t.Run("Successful Request", func(t *testing.T) {
          ts := httptest.NewServer(http.HandlerFunc(func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
              w.WriteHeader(200)
              fmt.Fprintf(w, "127.0.0.1")
          }))
          defer ts.Close()

          DefaultHTTPGetAddress = ts.URL

          _, err := handler(events.APIGatewayProxyRequest{})
          if err != nil {
              t.Fatal("Everything should be ok")
          }
      })
  }
  ```

I want the breakpoint to be hit, in UI, when I debug main.go or main_test.go.

UPDATE:

After I downgraded my VS Code to 1.30.2 and installed Go extension and Delve, I get the following error when I debug:

"Debug adapter process has terminated unexpectedly (read error)"

Answer (score 1):

I solved it as follows:

- Deleted the '%USERPROFILE%\.vscode\extensions\ms-vscode.go-0.11.4' folder alone & reinstalled Go extension -- It did NOT work
- Deleted the entire '%USERPROFILE%\.vscode' folder & reinstalled Go extension -- It worked :)

Some other extension was erroneous and so the Go debug failed to work. Cleaning all the extensions fixed it.

Hope, this might be useful to others.